# Different plots in numerical solution for a D.E in different computers

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration

I have the following situation.

I received a piece of code that plots the solution to a certain D.E. When I open the notebook I see the following.

```
m := 1.0
psi[r_] := ArcCos[m/r]

M := 2.8

NDSolve[{(1 - 
       m^2/r^2) (3 r^3 th[r] - (m^4 + 4 m^2 r^2 - 5 r^4) Derivative[
         1][th][r] + r (m^2 - r^2)^2 (th^\[Prime]\[Prime])[r]) + 
    M^2  r Sin[psi[r]]^3 th[r]/ Sqrt[ 1 + r^2 D[psi[r], r]^2]   == 0, 
  th[10] == 1/10^3,  th'[10.] == -3/10^4}, th, {r, 1.0001, 10}]

Plot[ th[r] /. %, {r, 1.0001, 10}]

{{th -> InterpolatingFunction[{{1.0001, 10.}}, <>]}}
```

and the plot is.

[image: Plot 1]

When I run the same command in my computer, I get he following

[image: Plot2]

Question 1: Do you know why this might be happening?

Question 2: Which of the plots is the right one?

Question 3: If my plot is the wrong one, what do I do to fix the situation?

Thanks

Comment: Is `th^\[Prime]\[Prime]` supposed to be the second derivative of `th`?

Comment: Yes, it is the second derivative

Comment: After making some replacements (`th'`->`Derivative[1][th]` etc), I get the same plot as you.

Comment: Thank you @Kiro. Cheers!!!

Comment: As graphs, they look equivalent, i.e. the same except for the placement of the axes origin.  (See the option `AxesOrigin`.)  Perhaps there are different versions of Mathematica on the two machines, or someone has fiddled with the settings (e.g. in init.m).  I cannot test that hypothesis without access to the machines themselves.

Comment: Thank you for that @MichaelE2